# Freezing Landscape orientation on SFSafariViewController on modal style presentation iOS13

Tags: ios, objective-c, modalviewcontroller, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm presenting SFSafariViewController on app, but on Landscape doesn't fit the screen, also done/back button doesn't work - freezing. The controller is presenting as modal. When presenting full screen it works as it should. Is any option for showing SFSafariViewController full screen on modal controllers.

[image]

```
  guard let webUrl = NSURL(string: url) else { return }
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: webUrl as URL)
    restrictRotation(true)
    self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    safariVC.delegate = self

-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction {
    AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    appDelegate.shouldRotate = restriction;
}
```

App delegate:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
if (self.shouldRotate) {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
} else {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

}

Comment: code is required?

Comment: I added the code